# compute $\int( \sin^2{\frac{1}{x^2}})dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Hello I need solve this
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\varepsilon}^{1/n} \left(n^{4/7}\sin{\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)^2dx$$
try to do this

$$\sin^2{\frac{1}{x^2}}=1/2\left(1-\cos{\frac{2}{x^2}}\right)$$

I still don't know how integral $(1-\cos{\frac{2}{x^2}})$
I already tried with wolfram but I want to know how to do it.
Can you help me please?

An apology if it's trivial, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: What is the significance of the parameter $n$?

Comment: Do you plan on taking $n \to \infty$ afterwards? If so then you don’t even need to evaluate the integral, just bound it from above

Comment: @MarkViola I am trying to find the normal convergence of the Lebesgue space $L ^ 2 [0,1]$of my function $f_n (x)$ is defined by $n^{4/7} \sin {\frac{1} {x ^ 2}}, \in (0,\frac{1} /{ n})$
And in the notes I have he asks me to solve it like this. Oh, is there another way?

Comment: @JackT could you show me how to do it please? Thanks

Comment: What happens upon enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto 1/{\sqrt x}$?

Comment: @MarkViola Oh, I owe you one, you are the best